# Pandoc conversion from wiki file to Docx with table of content

Tags: ms-word, docx, wiki, pandoc

I am using Pandoc to convert my document into different format

https://pandoc.org/

i create WIKI document and by using Pandoc i convert them to different format

lets suppose we have created wiki file with following content

```
=test =


{| 
|-
! width="40%"| '''g1''' 
! width="60%"|  
|-
|'''''Activity0'''''
|Item 1 
|}
{| 
|-
! width="40%"| '''g2''' 
! width="60%"| '''''' 
|-
|'''''Activity4'''''
|Item 2 
|}
```

when i convert this command

`pandoc -s a.wiki -o a.docx`

it generate docx and word file is opening without any issue

but when i want to have TOC (table of content) in my word file i use

`pandoc --toc -s a.wiki -o a.docx`

it generate docx and word file is opening with this issue

[image]

i am not sure what and why this is coming

is there any solution or link where it guide me to solution , i have tried to google it but not able to find it yet

Comment: what happens if you click yes/no ? if there's no problem.. i guess there's no problem ;)

Comment: @mb21 yes when i click yes TOC load but when you click any of link in TOC it do not take it to that location :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with wrong links in the text. In my case, i tried to make internal link on image, which based under the text. Link didn't work, but when i past 2-3 new line symbols before and after image link, it became ok. I don't know why, but pandoc need's some empty lines before and after image link.